# Is it possible to convert my PyQt5 GUI App into a webapp using django?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new to Python, I'm still learning but I have already done some first steps and I have created some GUI's with the QtDesigner tool, which looks like this:

GUI 1:
[image: GUI 1]

GUI 2:
[image: GUI 2]

GUI 3:
[image: GUI 3]

Number 2 is quite functional already (at least for me: D), it has animated menu, it collects data from my sensors and draws charts ([github)](https://github.com/d-szuffy/Sensors-App-GUI). And now my question is: is there any way to apply this code/this GUIs into a webapplication using Django? I mean, I would like to make this a webapp and I don't want to start designing from zero once again and I wonder if I could somehow use what I've already done.

Mateusz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTdesigner exports to XML, whereas Django uses HTML, CSS and JS for rendering Pages, there is no real way to transfer XML to html so it will need to be done by hand

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to translate the GUI program code to Django code yourself...
Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick response!